# Converting a unix timestmap to Datetime using Zoho CRM

Tags: unix-timestamp, zoho, zoho-deluge

I'm writing a custom function in Deluge that will take a unix timestamp and convert it to a date string in Eastern Standard Time.

For testing purposes, I have a unix timestamp of `1671718987466`

This is equal to  `Thu Dec 22 2022 09:23:07 GMT-0500` (Eastern Standard Time)

When I test the script in Zoho's Deluge playground using the `.toString()` method, it gives me the correct values:

```cs
    unix = 1671718987466;
    unixString = unix.toString("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", "America/New_York");
    info "Converted unix to date string: " + unixString;
```

This is the output for the code above:

[image]

---

But when I write the exact same lines of code in Zoho CRM function editor, I get an incorrect value that is 3 hours off:

[image]

Does anyone have an explanation and a solution for this?

I tried this [solution](https://help.zoho.com/portal/en/community/topic/crm-convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-datetime) but sadly it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Please allow me to apologize first as I am putting this as answer instead of comment as I do not have the required reputation.

Could you check the timezone being used in your organization or user?
Is it also Eastern Standard Timezone?

Usually, the function will auto-convert the value based on that.

If that was the case, then it could be that your function is using PST or PDT (depends on the date).
And you would need Zoho Support to clarify for that.

Comment: But the unix timestamp is supposedly UTC, would it really matter?

Comment: Which means it is indeed using PST timezone. I also had a case when running a scheduler which translates the date wrongly (in my case). As the schedule run using the company timezone, while the date in function is using PST/PDT. This led me to tinker the function and the schedule to run at the correct time to get the correct result.

Comment: Can you explain the PST timezone thing in detail? as it going over my head

Comment: That timestamp sample you gave, 1671718987466, will be converted as 2022-12-22T14:23:07+00:00, which is UTC. As the function ran in PST, the hour will be minus 8 and the result is as yours, 2022-12-22T06:23:07+00:00. Why is it ran in PST you asked? That is the thing you need to clarify with their support team.